# How to load longitude and latitude information into cesium kmlDataSource?

Tags: cesiumjs

I want to display the kml file in cesium [globe](https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium-workshop), and as described in the cesium's [workshop code](https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium-workshop), we need to load the file by passing it with the file location (or URL). The following line of code is the specific line of code that cesium loads the kml.

```
var geocachePromise = Cesium.KmlDataSource.load('./Source/SampleData/sampleGeocacheLocations.kml', kmlOptions);
```

The entire code is available [here](https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium-workshop/blob/master/Source/App.js#L92)

My question is: I have the longitude, and latitude, (and height) information saved in variables and instead of always saving them into .kml file and then load them via folder, I want to pass this information to cesium kmlDataSource (the code above) directly.

It would be great if anyone has any solution to this.
Please let me know if further information or code snapshot is required. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the information you need stored in JavaScript variables, there's no need to export to KML and import it back into Cesium.  You can directly add the indicators you need as Cesium Entities, which is what the KML loader is creating when it reads a KML.

Typically, a KML-like pin is represented by a Cesium Entity containing either a `point` or a `billboard`, and optionally an associated `label`.

Here are some relevant demos that show how this is done:

- [Billboard demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Billboards.html)
- [Map Pin demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Map%20Pins.html)
- [Label demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Labels.html)

Each of these demos calls `viewer.entities.add({ ... })` along with a position for the Entity and some sort of graphical indication(s) to display to the user.  You may place one of each on an Entity, for example a `billboard` and a `label` are often both defined when adding a typical KML-like Entity.

If your data is stored on the server however, you will need some mechanism to stream it to the browser.  CZML is Cesium's native format for doing so, but KML is also available as an alternative for certain kinds of graphics.  You may also use any API of your own design, and create Entities when the data becomes available in JavaScript.